# How to solve Laravel URL in a loop problem?

Tags: php, laravel, analyzer

I have a category URL like this :

```
example.com/shop/category-name
```

And this is my **web.php** :

```
/* Categories Route */
Route::any('shop/{slug}', 'CategoryController@category')->name('category');
```

But when I analyze my website, I have this /shop in all of the URLs (Routes) :

[image: analyze image]

Why I have this /shop in all of routes ?
Tell me if you want details
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a / before your shop so you make sure the route starts from the right place (or any other one that fits you, slash meaning home) :

```
Route::any('/shop/{slug}', 'CategoryController@category')->name('category');
```

With your syntax, you're basically telling laravel that any url with "shop/{something}" contained in it redirects to the @category method.

Comment: I put / before all routes, but still I have this problem

Comment: And do these weird routes even work or are they just on the graph ?

Comment: Yes my routes works fine, but I have this problem in graph

Comment: No i mean if you go to /help-center/shop/shop/shop/shop what shows up

Comment: I got 404 Error

Answer (score 0):

If you are using external js file and using ajax, you might need to look at the way your route is set. I am using Laravel v.8 and assuming your route's lists check out as you have claimed.  Try adding forward slash before shop as shown below.

////////////////etc.

$.ajax({

```
    url: 'shop', //Initial state this can cause you having shop/shop
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      $foo: $bar
    },
```

////////////etc.

////////////////etc.

$.ajax({

```
    url: '/shop',  ////Final State; this eliminated extra shop for me
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      $foo: $bar
    },
```

////////////etc.